# Is a classmap required to receive complex data via the PHP SOAP client?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm wondering if anyone can help with my PHP SOAP client problem. I'm trying to consume but the 'Request' details appears to be a multi-dimensional array.

> https://llu.webservices.opalonline.co.uk/NGAAvailabilityCheckerWSV1/NGAAvailabilityCheckerWS.asmx?WSDL

Here's my code so far:

```
    function NGACheck($cli) {

    $url =     "https://llu.webservices.opalonline.co.uk/NGAAvailabilityCheckerWSV1/NGAAvailabilityCheckerWS.asmx?WSDL";
    $client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));

        $data = array(
           'request' => array(
                'RequestDetails' => array(
                        'TelephoneNumberRequest' => array(
                                'TelephoneNumber'=>'01611234567')),
                'ServiceType' => 'All',
                'UserCredentials' => array(
                        'Username' => 'james@test.net',
                        'Password' => 'mypassword',
                        'AgentID' => '1234'),
                'UserConsent' => 'Yes',
        ));

        print_r($data);


    $method = 'GetNGAAvailability';
    $result = $client->$method(new SoapParam($data,'Data'));

//    $EFMPrice = (array) $result->SearchResponseDetail;


  return $EFMPrice;
   echo $client->__getLastRequest();
   echo $client->__getLastResponse();
}

print_r(NGACheck());
```

When I run the code, I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal Server Error       
in /usr/utils/test.php:26
```

Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to build a classmap?

I'm not sure how to present the data to the SOAP server.

Comment: I realise this is quite old, but did you find the answer to your problem? Having the same issue.